# Numerical Double integration with endpoint singularity in scipy Python gives incorrect answer

Tags: quadrature, scipy, mathematica

I am trying to integrate the following function in Python,

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x-y}}{B(x,y)}dx dy$,

where $B(x,y)$ is the beta function - $B(x,y) = \int_0^{1}a^{x-1}(1-a)^{y-1}da$.

As the above function was not directly integrable in `scipy.integrate`, I did a change of variable, $x\rightarrow e^{-x},y\rightarrow e^{-y}$ to have

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{B(-\log (x),-\log (y))}dx dy$.

`scipy.integrate.dblquad(lambda y,x: 1/ scipy.special.beta(-math.log(x),-math.log(y) ),  0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1)`

returns $6.81\ldots$ with error in order of $10^{-6}$. But  integrating the above functions (with and without change of variable) in Mathematica (using `NIntegrate`) returns $2.0505\ldots$. I do not understand this huge difference in answer when python returns an answer with $10^{-6}$ accuracy. Whats happening? Is there a better way to integrate it in python? I plan to perform the integration many number of times as part of an algorithm written in python.

$\frac{1}{B(-\log (x),-\log (y))}$ looks like this

[image: singularity at (0,0)]

**Edit**

Can someone with Windows 10 and Anaconda reproduce the results I get?

I get the incorrect answer using Windows 10, Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit), scipy version 0.18.1. I am not sure about the BLAS linkage.

I get the correct answer in Linux using Python 2.7.12, scipy version 0.18.1

Comment: I get `(2.0505570600455982, 4.867808183917077e-05)` when I run the python code (scipy version: `0.18.1`).

Comment: Wow! Mine is also `0.18.1`, using Python 3.5 in Spyder IDE. I don't get it..Though I get this warning `IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.`

Comment: @ Stelios - I tried it in an online python here [link](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/) and I get `(2.0505570600455982, 4.867808183917077e-05)` . But in Ipython console in Spyder in my local machine I get `(6.8194728123941895, 2.7699807105818763e-06)` . I tried it in a friends laptop with Spyder and I get `6.81.` as well. I am confused.. Maybe Spyder has something wrong..

Comment: Very weird... I use Python 3.6 and Jupyter (IPython), BTW. Try posting this on stackoverflow SE to see if this issue can be reproduced by other users.

Comment: Also, from your script, print `scipy.__version__` to check that you are using the right version from the current interpreter.

Comment: @Pierre, I did that, its using 0.18.1 in the script I am running

Comment: Ok, here spyder 2.3.8, Python 3.5, SciPy 0.18.1, and I have the same results as Stelios. SciPy depends on system libraries (libgfortran and blas), can you provide more details on your platform? (OS, method of installation for Python, gfortran, blas and scipy)

Comment: @ Pierre, Thanks for testing it out. These are the details of my platform-

Comment: @Pierre, These are the details of my platform- (windows 10 OS,method of installation -  Anaconda, Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit), scipy version 0.18.1, ). Blas version - Based on the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000164/how-to-check-blas-lapack-linkage-in-numpy-scipy) I get the following answer.  blas_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\conda-bld\\scipy_1484093924421\\_b_env\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']

Comment: Sorry, I have no windows 10 machine to test a reproduction of the bug. Add your platform information in the original question and ask if someone on Win 10 with anaconda can reproduce. If so, a bug report can be filed to Anaconda.

Comment: Can you check if you are affected by this bug too? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6882

Comment: @Kirill - I made the changes suggested to `intel.py`, but I am unsure how to recompile quadpack form anaconda (sorry I am new to python). I still get 6.81. I tried running the integration present in the link you provided and it gives an Incorrect answer for my machine as well.

Comment: Using win 7, python 3.5 32-bit, scipy 0.18.1 + MKL (from Christophe Gohlke) I get the same results as OP. Might be linked to MKL?

Comment: Got the new binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy and the problem was resolved. It was indeed apparently linked to the bug mentionned by Kirill

Comment: Was this info sent to the Anaconda people?

Comment: Yes, My issue was also resolved by reinstalling numpy and scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy .Thanks Krill for pointing it out! Any idea how to send a bug report to anaconda?

Comment: @SiddharthaSatpathi Try https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues